# Should I use ViewModelScope independent of Fragment's lifecycle?

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin-coroutines, android-viewmodel

TL;DR

For one instance of a fragment, that is added/removed again and again, `viewModelScope` in its ViewModel only works until the first time fragment is popped. After this, `viewModelScope` becomes inactive. How can I reinitialize the `viewModelScope` when I add the fragment back? Or Should I look for a better implementation to keep it active?

Scenario:

I have used `RxJava` through `ViewModel` to retrieve data from network in an old project, and to send the updates to UI, I have used LiveData.

Following is how I initialised a typical ViewModel inside a fragment:

```
private val fruitsViewModel by viewModels<FruitsViewModel>()
```

Following is the above mentioned ViewModel:

```
class FruitsViewModel: ViewModel {

    private var category: String = FruitCategories.DEFAULT

    private val _fruits = MutableLiveData<List<Fruit>>()
    fun fruits(): LiveData<List<Fruit>> = _fruits

    fun updateCategory(newCategory: String) {
        this.category = newCategory
        fetchFruits()
    }

    fun fetchFruits() { ... }
}
```

In Fragment's `onViewCreated()`, I called `fruitsViewModel.fetchFruits()`. This worked great(without any visible problems).

Today, I switched RxJava specific code with coroutines to retrieve network data in my ViewModel. Something like this:

```
fun fetchFruits() {

    /* this.fruitsJob = */ 
    viewModelScope.launch {
        ...
    }
}
```

This works good too, even after I replace a fragment and come back to it. But, if I *keep* a fragment instance declared in Activity, and use it again, `viewModelScope.launch {}` doesn't work anymore. Something like this:

```
class FruitsActivity: AppCompatActivity() {

    private val fruitsFragment = FruitsFragment()

    private fun showFruitsFragment() {
        supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(getFragmentContainerId(), fruitsFragment)
            .addToBackStack(fruitsFragment.tag)
            .commit()
    }

    private fun removeFragments() {
        val manager = supportFragmentManager
        if (manager.backStackEntryCount > 0) {

            val first: FragmentManager.BackStackEntry = manager.getBackStackEntryAt(0)
            manager.popBackStack(first.id, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE)
        }
    }
}
```

The reason for keeping the fragment instance is to load API data only once, and after that, it should just appear on the click of a button without any flicker/loading.

After I call `removeFragments()`, `fruitsViewModel` has already called its `onCleared()` for *kept* declaration of `fruitsFragment`. So, its `viewModelScope` becomes inactive, and if I add `fruitsFragment` back again by calling `showFruitsFragment()`, this will not retrieve network data anymore. This was not the case for my Rxjava implementation because I didn't use `viewModelScope`.

I think I can just fix the problem by linking `fruitsViewModel` to `FruitsActivity`'s instance instead. But, I want to know if this can be considered as the best way.

Comment: `The reason for keeping the fragment instance is to load API data only once` so then it sounds like you need a shared view model, doesn't it ? why not attach the view model to the activity and have it do service calls as you need to

Comment: Agree with @a_local_nobody . Since you keep the fragment longer (similar to the lifetime of the activity) regardless of how many times it's attached and detached, it's better to use the activity's scope or activity's view model.

Comment: Btw, since you want to retain the loaded data independent from the fragment's lifecycle, the data should be stored within the activity instead of the fragment. IMO, keeping fragment instances is not a good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should scope your `viewModel` differently, in your case scoping `fruitsViewModel` to `FruitsActivity` makes complete sense.

I'm not sure how your `RxJava` code worked, without seeing the code I'm guessing, that it has something to do with it not being `disposed` correctly.

Also, even if you would create a scope, that outlives the `viewModelScope` (for ex: create and maintain a `CoroutineScope` in the activity) my main issue is that approach is **not intuitive/natural**, people will have a harder time checking how & where is that `CoroutineScope` maintained

Comment: Agreed, thanks. p.s. RxJava related implementation disposed all disposables in ViewModel's `onCleared()` method. This allows new calls after onCleared() because RxJava is not linked to any lifecycle. But, for coroutines, I am dependent on `viewModelScope` which is linked to lifecycle(?).

Comment: Hmm, I wonder how the implementation is different, because technically `viewModelScope` cancels the coroutine at `onCleared()`

Comment: RxJava implementation didn't depend on coroutines or `viewModelScope`. `fetchFruits()` was just like a method in any other class.